# Returning the average of a List, if such a list exists

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I want to make it so the average of a List of floats is returned (as a float) if the list passed as an argument is a list of floats, and not anything else e.g. a list of ints. It should only compute the average if its a list of floats.

So say I pass a list of ints, then it should return the none statement. Or if I pass an empty list, it should also return the none statement.

```
let avg x = 
    let average = List.averageBy (fun elem -> float elem) x

    match List.tryFind x with
    |Some(x) -> printfn "The average of the list is %f" average
    |None -> "There are no float elements in the list, hence no average"

avg [1.0;5.0;6.0;10.0]
```

getting the error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type ''a->bool' but here has type ''b list'.

Which makes sense. I can however not figure out where to give it a bool value.

EDIT

I am considering using List.forall to check if the list contains floats. Still running into the same BOOL problem.

Comment: Why do you need to check if the list is a list of floats? The type system will do it for you. Just do ``List.average [your list]``.

Comment: Its an assignment I have. So I have to use specific functions from the List library. I can easily just calculate the average of the list by using my first statement, but I want to use List.tryFind and an Option, so it will return the average giving there is a list, and my string giving its none.

Comment: What do you mean when by "if such a list exists"? If what kind of lists exists? The only list here is the list of floats that you get as an argument and that one exists because otherwise you couldn't have gotten it as an argument. You seem to be trying to use `tryFind` to check whether the list is empty (which is not the same as not existing), but that's not what tryFind is for, you'd use `List.isEmpty` for that.

Comment: Well, I need to check if the list passed as an argument is a list of floats, and not anything else e.g. a list of ints. 
It should only compute the average if its a list of floats.

Comment: Do you know what is strong typing ?

Comment: as has already been written, why don't you just write: `List.average [1.0;5.0;6.0;10.0]` ?

Comment: Because that is not enough to complete the assignment I was given. 

I need to use specific functions from the List library and I need an Option as well.

Comment: so, you should be able to pass to the function anything you like?

Comment: Well sure, but it should not compute the average unless its a List of floats. If I pass ANYTHING ELSE, it should give me None.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125521/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-kthonenice).

Comment: What is the type of the argument? Is it an `obj list`, `obj` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Shortcut to Answer

The following assumes you're being passed a list of varying types, which I'm assuming you are since you said you had to use functions from the `List` module.

```
let average list =
    let isFloat (x : obj) =
        match x with
        | :? float -> true
        | _        -> false
    let toFloat (x : obj) = x :?> float
    if List.forall isFloat list then
        List.averageBy toFloat list
        |> Some
    else None
```

---

### Explanation

The reason you are getting your compiler error is because your `List.tryFind` use is incorrect, but that's not the complete story.  A correct usage of `tryFind` looks like

```
let findFirstEven list = List.tryFind (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) list
```

F# is strongly-typed, which means that *in general*, we expect that you don't try to pass multiple types to functions.  Functions expect exactly one type for each argument, and it is a compile-time error to pass something different.

That said, because F# is built on .NET and supports classes and inheritance, it is possible for a function to take a class, but for it to do different things if the actual passed object is a derived class of the expected one.  In F#, that type coercion test is done like so:

```
type Person (name) =
    member this.Name : string = name

type Student (name, university) =
    inherit Person (name)
    member this.University : string = university

type Adult (name, job) =
    inherit Person (name)
    member this.Job : string = job

let greet (person : Person) =
    match person with
    | :? Student as student -> printfn "Hello, %s of %s" student.Name student.University
    | :? Adult   as adult   -> printfn "Hello, %s.  I hope you enjoy working at %s!" adult.Name adult.Job
    | _                     -> printfn "Nice to meet you, %s" person.Name
```

This only works for derived types, and not for true F# generic types like trying to match `'T list` with `float list` or whatever.  The way .NET is structured, though, means that every possible type is either `obj`, or derives from `obj`.  This means if we're allowed to be passed any possible type, we can test whether it's a `float list` or not.

```
let average (value : obj) =
    match value with
    | :? List<float> as list -> List.average list |> Some
    | _ -> None
```

This function can take literally any expressible type, so it's something we really *really* try to get away from writing in F#.  Let's say instead that you can guarantee that you're going to be passed a list of things, but the things could be different types from each other.  Again, this is a situation we definitely try to avoid when writing F#, but for now:

```
let average list =
    let isFloat (x : obj) =
        match x with
        | :? float -> true
        | _        -> false
    let toFloat (x : obj) = x :?> float
    if List.forall isFloat list then
        List.averageBy toFloat list
        |> Some
    else None
```

This individually tests whether each element of the list is a `float`, then if so casts the list elements to `float` and averages them.  The downcast `:?>` is needed because otherwise `List.average` doesn't know how to perform the average (it still thinks the list could be anything), but it's also a dangerous operator to use carelessly.  If the cast to the derived type fails, then the code will throw an exception, which could terminate your program.  Here we know it's safe because we just tested the same cast, but you should avoid using it in your code unless you're certain it's safe.  Even then, this doesn't make for idiomatic F# code, because we mostly expect you to use true generics to make proper use of the type system.

Comment: Thank you for a great and in depth answer. Definitely makes sense. Still trying to grasp this language. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something which should work :

```
let avg (arg : obj) =
  match arg with
    :? list<float> as xs -> Some (List.average xs)
  | _                    -> None
```

or (same thing, another way to write it) :

```
let avg : obj -> _ = function
  :? list<float> as xs -> Some (List.average xs)
| _                    -> None
```